# How to generate random numbers with a skewed normal distribution in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to generate 1000 sets of 130 random numbers which fit the skewed normal distribution of the numbers below:

```
-10.4, -9.3, -6.8, -4.8, -5.7, -5.8, -4.5, -3.4, -2, 0.3, -0.4, -4.1, -6.9, -5.9, -2.5, -2, -2.8, -3.2, -4.4, -2, -1.4, 0.9, -1, -4.1, -11.7, 0.1
```

The mean of these numbers is -3.99, the standard deviation is 3.17, the skew is -0.71 and the kurtosis is 0.22.

I would really like to be able to do it using Excel formulae, as I am a complete novice with VBA, and I need to repeat this exercise with different means, SDs and skews. I also want to be able to understand it, and VBA is another language to me.

Comment: Honestly would do this in something other than Excel.

Comment: I suppose I could do them somewhere else and copy them in. I can work with SQL and R. Is there a solution in either of those languages?

Comment: Not an R person but I'd give that a shot and ask a new question as necessary (showing what you've tried).

Comment: If anyone has a solution in R, please put it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456442/how-to-generate-random-numbers-with-skewed-normal-distribution-in-r)